# Undefined index when assign $_SESSION['somthing'] to a variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to load last session with the inner AJAX call after reload page, but it fires notice: Undefined index cat when using `$cat = $_SESSION['cat'];`
but when using  `$cat = $_REQUEST['cat'];` it works fine but didn't restore session.

`categories.php`

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION['cat'])){
   echo $_SESSION['cat'] ;
  }
```

and this file call in `ajax: loadScat.php`

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['cat'])){
    echo $_SESSION['cat'] ;
    }
    $cat = $_SESSION['cat']; // here says undefined index cat!
```

I want to restore last category i clicked with inner ajax call, how can i do  that, and why it shows that error above? thenx alot ...

Comment: session_start(); start must got at the top of every page before any output. Make sure on the second page also..

Comment: Well did you define `$_SESSION['cat']` ?

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU in both pages it's after `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` .. and when removing it .. nothing change

Comment: @Daan what do you mean? how to define it?

Comment: Ok.. @HalaElBarchah.. you need to assign $_SESSION['cat'] = 'any words'; and get session variable on ajax ..

Comment: @b0s3 if you mean something like `if(isset($_SESSION['cat'])){
    echo $_SESSION['cat'] ;
    $cat = $_SESSION['cat'];
}`  it doesnt work too

Answer (score 0):

**Everytime restart your browser as it is a session variable**

`categories.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$_SESSION['cat'] = "Sample String";
 if(isset($_SESSION['cat'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['cat'] ;
  } else {
    $cat =" Your Session has not been set and this page is <b>categories.php</b>";
    echo $cat;
 }
```

`ajax: loadScat.php`

```
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_SESSION['cat'])){
   echo $_SESSION['cat'] ;
  } else 
  {
    $cat =" Your Session has not been set";
    echo $cat;
 }
```

Comment: thanx, but the error become Undefined variable: cat  in loadScat.php when i try to use it in something later,,,
also, the result of ajax call doesnt appear, and the page include only the 'sample string' !!!

Comment: @HalaElBarchah Once try running the code after commenting                                     $_SESSION['cat'] = "Sample String";

Comment: @HalaElBarchah also in categories.php you are checking that if session variable is set. but if it's not set then give the else part to assign it a default value.

Comment: Okay, there are two echo in loadScat.php .. on of them for showing list, and the other is that after `isset($_SESSION['cat'])` in code above,, is that causing problems?

Comment: @HalaElBarchah I have edited answer check the updated answer.

Comment: I did ,, and still not working .. even after commenting  ` $_SESSION['cat'] = "Sample String";` still shows the "sample string",,

Comment: in the post in fireBug ,, the category id is always 1 after reloading page